# ABC анализ в Power Query

Tags: powerquery

подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше прописать формулу в Power Query. Необходимо провести АВС анализ для каждой подкатегории. Для каждой подкатегории необходимо задать свое ранжирование т.е. в категории 1, товар A, определяется до 80%, а в категории 2, товар A определяется до 85%, а в категории 3, товар A определяется до 70%.
Пример с описанием (скрин_1)

**(скрин_1)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

1. Возможно ли создать новую таблицу (скрин_2) с определением границ категорий для каждой подгруппы и ссылаться на это значение в функции? Если можно, то как это сдлелать и будет ли это быстрее первого варианта

**(скрин_2)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)